# Java static polymorphism (overloading) and inheritance between generics

Tags: java, generics, java-11, overload-resolution, static-polymorphism

Java 11 (may be irrelevant):

```
public static String toString(Object obj) {
    return ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(obj, ToStringStyle.SHORT_PREFIX_STYLE);
}

public static String toString(Collection<Object> collection) {
    return collection.stream()
            .map(SaLogUtils::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "[", "]"));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = List.of(Integer.valueOf(1));
    System.out.println(SaLogUtils.toString(list));
    System.out.println(SaLogUtils.toString(List.of(Integer.valueOf(1))));
}
```

Surprising output:

```
// from toString(Object)
ImmutableCollections.List12[e0=1,e1=<null>]
// from toString(Collection<Object>)
[Integer[value=1]]
```

Why does Java statically choose different methods?

Comment: There is, by the way, no reason to use `Integer.valueOf(1)`. You can simply write `List.of(1)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When there are multiple overloads which could be invoked, Java chooses [the most specific applicable method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5):

> The informal intuition is that one method is more specific than another if any invocation handled by the first method could be passed on to the other one without a compile-time error. In cases such as an explicitly typed lambda expression argument (§15.27.1) or a variable arity invocation (§15.12.2.4), some flexibility is allowed to adapt one signature to the other.

---

`toString(Collection<Object>)` isn't applicable for a `List<Integer>`, because [a `List<Integer>` isn't a `List<Object>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265/3788176), so it's not a `Collection<Object>` either. As such, only the `toString(Object)` method is applicable, so that's the one that is invoked.

---

`toString(Collection<Object>)` is applicable for `List.of(someInteger)` because that `List.of` is a polyexpression: it could be `List<Integer>`, it could be `List<Object>`, it could be `List<Serializable>`.

Since both `toString(Object)` and `toString(Collection<Object>)` are applicable, it has to choose one or the other (or declare it ambiguous). The `Collection` overload is more specific because:

- Anything you pass to `toString(Collection<Object>)` can also be passed to `toString(Object)`
- But there are things you can pass to `toString(Object)` that can't be passed to `toString(Collection<Object>)` (such as `new Object()`).

This makes the `toString(Collection<Object>)` more specific, so this is the one that is chosen.

Comment: As an addendum, the likely intended fix to the problem is to change the signature to `toString(Collection<?> collection)`…